# Sending an email with ASP .Net and Gmail SMTP

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, gmail

I am developping an ASP .Net website.
One of my ASPX page contains a button.
When this button is clicked I want to send an email by using the Gmail SMTP server.
I want to use my Gmail account as credentials.

Here is the button's click event handler :

```
protected void m_myButton_Click(object p_sender, EventArgs p_args)
{
    string l_subject = "My subject";

    StringBuilder l_builder = new StringBuilder();
    // ...
    string l_body = l_builder.ToString();

    string l_host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"];
    int l_port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);

    NameValueCollection l_smtpAccount = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("smtpAccount");
    string l_address = l_smtpAccount["SmtpAddress"];
    string l_password = l_smtpAccount["SmtpPassword"];

    MailMessage l_mail = new MailMessage();
    l_mail.From = new MailAddress(l_address);
    l_mail.To.Add(l_address);
    l_mail.Subject = l_subject;
    l_mail.Body = l_body;

    SmtpClient l_smtp = new SmtpClient();
    l_smtp.Host = l_host; // l_host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    l_smtp.Port = l_port; // l_port = 587
    l_smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    l_smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    l_smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(l_address, l_password);

    l_smtp.Send(l_mail);
}
```

The command line l_smtp.Send(l_mail) fails.
A SMTP exception is raised and the InnerException property informs me that (translation from French to English) : No connection has been etablished because the target computer has refused it 173.194.67.108:587

My code is based on code found on this page : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/254743/sending-email-in-asp-net-using-smtp-gmail-server

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you connect to that server and port from your machine outside your ASP.NET code? e.g. `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` or use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) `putty -raw smtp.gmail.com 587`. It works for me from here (although I'm not trying SSL)

Comment: 1. Credentials - you should use not your email as login. I mean if your email is "mymail@gmail.com" - your login for Credentails should be "mymail", not "mymail@gmail.com" 2. l_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(l_address))

Comment: @Rup I have tried to connect to smtp.gmail.com by using telnet but I have got the error message : Connection refused. I had specified 587 as port number and raw as protocol. I have not tried to connect by using telnet because it does not inform of a successful or a failed connection.

Comment: @AlexOvechkin I have followed your two advices but I am still getting an exception

Comment: @user1139666 If you get a successful connection you'll get a message from the Google server e.g. `220 mx.google.com ESMTP gy2sm28975989wib.3 - gsmtp` and if you don't it'll time out. Does port 465 work? Port 25? Do you have any outbound firewall on this machine - can you try turning the firewall off temporarily? Might Google be blocking your subnet - can you try from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have turned my antivirus program off as advised by Rup and I have not got any exception.
I will created a custom rule in my antivirus program to allow communication between my ASP .Net website and the Gmail SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.To.Add("Email ID where email is to be send");
 mail.To.Add("Another Email ID where you wanna send same email");
 mail.From = new MailAddress("YourGmailID@gmail.com");
 mail.Subject = "Email using Gmail";

 string Body = "Hi, this mail is to test sending mail"+ 
             "using Gmail in ASP.NET";
 mail.Body = Body;

  mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
 smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
 smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
   ("YourUserName@gmail.com","YourGmailPassword");
//Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 smtp.Send(mail);
 }
```

Comment: No port number is specified. Is it normal ?

Comment: s if u want u can include the port number as smtp.port=587;

Comment: I tried port 465, then 587. First gave out timeout. Second gave credentials error. But using 25 as the port worked perfect! Also had to take out smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Answer (score 0):

No connection has been etablished because the target computer has refused it `73.194.67.108:587`

Try the other SMTP port: `465`

Comment: I have faced another exception informing me of a timeout